# Docusign, how to apply multiple server templates for a single document in sequence

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

In Docusign I have two server templates:

- template A has signature on the 3rd page.
- template B on 5th.

The document to be signed should replace the documents of the templates, and be a combination of A+B, so it would have signatures in 3rd and 8th page, it should combine the two server templates one AFTER another.

However, what's happening is that both templates get applied to the beginning of the document, so signatures are on pages 3 and 5.

How can I sequence the server templates to indicate they should not overlap over each other, be placed one after another instead?

Here is the composite template I'm trying to build to achieve that

```
{
    'composite_template_id': None,
    'document': {
        'document_base64': '...',
        'document_id': 3,
        'file_extension': 'pdf',
        'name': 'Sample file.pdf',
    },
    'server_templates': [
        {
            'sequence': '1',
            'template_id': 'e9e2******'
        },
        {
            'sequence': '2',
            'template_id': 'e269******'
        }
    ],
    'inline_templates': [
        {
            'recipients': {
                'carbon_copies': [],
                'signers': [
                    {
                        'client_user_id': '2',
                        'email': 'bobtest@example.com',
                        'name': 'Bob Test',
                        'recipient_id': '2',
                        'role_name': 'Signer',
                    }
                ],
                },
            'sequence': '3'
        }
    ],
}
```

Expected result: the document be signed with signatures in pages 3 and 8.
Current result: signatures are being placed in pages 3 and 5.

Answer (score 2):

When you apply a template to a document you are contributing, it takes all the non-document elements, i.e. recipients/roles, their tabs, and envelope settings and applies it to the provided document.  So that is why applying your two templates to the one document results in `signHere` tabs placed on pages 3 and 5.
To get your *desired* result, do one of the following:

- Make sure the second template has enough "padding pages" to cover the leading page content, so that the page numbering coincides with the contributed long document.
- Break (or retain) the long document as two separate documents.  Contribute two documents as two separate composites, applying the appropriate template to each.
- If the document is dynamically generated and the page length varies each time, use a different strategy to place the `signHere` tabs, i.e. use PDF fillable form fields and set `transformPdfFields` to true, or add anchor text to the text content and specify anchors (and maybe offsets) for the tab placement.